# cocoa -- What is the proper way to tell an NSWindow to redisplay its contents?

Tags: cocoa, drawing, nswindow

According to the [NSWindow Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you should "rarely need to invoke" the NSWindow methods "display" or "setViewsNeedDisplay".  So what is the usual way to redisplay the window's contents?

EDIT:  I am having trouble dealing with resizing events.  I just want to have everything scale proportionally.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640586/cocoa-getting-nested-nsviews-and-calayers-to-resize-proportionally).  As no one seems to have any ideas for using masks to get it to happen, I want to redraw the whole thing.

Comment: Generally you don't need to. Instead, you invalidate whatever view needs to be invalidated for whatever reason within the window.

Comment: In response to your edited addition: refreshing the whole window is *not* the solution to your problem. I suggest trying to elaborate on your other question by posting more detail AND CODE. No answer usually means you didn't provide enough detail and in most cases, more detail means "post your (relevant) code."

Answer (score 4):

[Jason's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676412/cocoa-what-is-the-proper-way-to-tell-an-nswindow-to-redisplay-its-contents#comment5155122_4676412) really should be an answer:

> Generally you don't need to. Instead, you invalidate whatever view needs to be invalidated for whatever reason within the window.

In addition to that comment, I'd add that you might want to explain why you feel you need to do this. While there are sometimes perfectly valid reasons to force the whole window to redraw, they are rare and you should suspect *You're Doing It Wrong™*.

Use this method to flag subviews for redisplay:

```
- setNeedsDisplay:YES
```