# Does NSView have anything analogous to UIView's setNeedsLayout/layoutSubviews methods?

Tags: cocoa, macos, layout, nsview

Do I put such things into the display method?  Or is there something analogous?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cocoa -- What is the proper way to tell an NSWindow to redisplay its contents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676412/cocoa-what-is-the-proper-way-to-tell-an-nswindow-to-redisplay-its-contents)

Comment: I think it's a different question.  One is asking how to tell the window to redisplay everything from scratch.  The other is asking about layout only.

Comment: Indeed: this is a different question.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with windows. It's related to NSView.

Answer (score 17):

As of OSX 10.7:

`- (void)layout` is equivalent to layoutSubviews

There is now an identical `setNeedsLayout`.

Override this method if your custom view needs to perform custom layout not expressible using the constraint-based layout system. In this case you are responsible for calling `setNeedsLayout:` when something that impacts your custom layout changes.

You may not invalidate any constraints as part of your layout phase, nor invalidate the layout of your superview or views outside of your view hierarchy. You also may not invoke a drawing pass as part of layout.

You must call `[super layout]` as part of your implementation.

Comment: This is for constraint-based layout only (aka `Auto Layout`)

Answer (score 13):

Analogous to `layoutSubviews` is the `resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:` method of `NSView`. I guess, analogous to `setNeedsLayout` would be calling `resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:[self frame].size` directly.

Answer (score 2):

resizeSubviewsWithOldSize: seems like it does nothing. Never gets called at all for me. Maybe it's because I use autolayout and the documentation says it's related to autoresizing.

NSView's **layout** appears to be the same as UIView's **layoutSubviews**. They're both overridable if you want to do some special work to replace or in addition to autoresizing or autolayout.

Calling this on UIView

```
[view setNeedsLayout];
```

seems to be the same as this on NSView

```
view.needsLayout = YES;
```

Which begs the question, why is "setNeedsLayout" even a function name? Like, really, you decided to remove the parameter from a setter function, and keep the "set" in the title? Why not "scheduleLayout"? This would obviate the need for Stack Overflow questions like this.

Comment: Thanks for posting your findings.

Comment: The reason is because there's no such thing as a write-only property and they don't want you querying this status. Why this distinction exists across platforms I can't say, pick one Apple!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, `resizeSubviewsWithOldSize` doesn't get called.
Then, try overriding `resizeWithOldSuperviewSize`.